# saving data as object or array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have some data like

```
4 0.128 0.039
5 0.111 0.037
6 0.095 0.036
```

I need to get the second and third value by a known first value. 
If I have a value of `4` I want to get back two variables: `a = 0.111` and `b = 0.037`

What would be the best variable type for storing the data shown above to get simple access to the data? An object or an multidimensional array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ease of access, I'd go with an object containing arrays:

```
{
    '4': [ 0.128, 0.039 ],
    '5': [ 0.111, 0.037 ],
    ... 
}
```

A second reason for the use of objects over arrays is ease of iteration. Imagine this:

```
var myData = [];
myData[4]  = [ 0.128, 0.039 ];
myData[10] = [ 42, 23 ];

for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++)
{
    console.log(myData[i]);
}
```

Would give you

```
null
null
null
null
[ 0.128, 0.039 ]
null
null
null
null
null
[ 42, 23 ]
```

... which is probably not what you want ;)

Comment: If `var x = 4`, how do I access the values? `data.x[0]` and `data.x[1]`?

Comment: @user3848987 use bracket notation: `data[x][0]`, and so forth ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you would want to do is save it as a json object or just as an array as shown below:

Creating:

```
var obj = { "4":[0.128, 0.039], "5":[0.111, 0.037],"6":[0.095, 0.036] }
```

Retrieving:

```
obj.4 -> [0.128, 0.039] OR obj['4'] OR obj[0]
obj.5[0] -> 0.111 OR obj['5'][0] OR obj[1][0]
obj.5[1] -> 0.037 OR obj['5'][1] OR obj[1][1]
```

Cycling through retrieved obj:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    alert(obj[key]); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally use arrays if the order of the elements is of importance, otherwise I use objects (objects are not good for preserving order).

- Arrays come with methods like push(),pop(),sort(),splice().
- Objects are good if you have a unique key.

In the end it comes down to what is the best tool for what is that you want to accomplish.